# Connecting to Hbase with Ruby

Tags: ruby, hbase, thrift

quite new to Hbase - can anyone recommend any full tutorials or examples of how to connect to HBase using ruby?

So far I've tried using an old version of Thrift and the code compiles @transport and @protocol, but dies on @client, probably because of the old version.

I'm using HBase in a VM and not sure how to generate a Thrift client package, as far as I understand, thrift --gen [lang] [hbase-root]/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift will generate a gen-rb file inside the vm. Do I then use this file in my ruby code ($:.push('./gen-rb') ) ?

Alternatively, should I forget about Thrift and instead use Massive Record?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been writing about using HBase within Ruby in a day-to-day practical sense.

You might want to check [this introductory post I wrote about it](http://www.jlescure.com/blog/hadoop-for-rubyists-quick-intro-to-hbase/), it has working examples which you can use to handle your HBase cluster from the outside using pure ruby.

At the end of that post I also keep a list of links to other posts and tutorials I'll continue writing on the subject.

**EDIT**

Also, about Thrift vs Massive Record, I would suggest you stick to Thrift.

Thrift has come a long way since its first gem was published and it actually is Apache's answer to accessing HBase externally.